# Google Maps Api markers array node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

i'm trying to pass a function that brings an array to the google maps api v3.
here's my code:

```
function buscarCoords(callback){
      var result = result;
      connection.query('SELECT * FROM monitoreo_actual', function(err, result){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
          callback({result:result});
      });
}

function initialize() {
          //var location = new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.191);
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.191),
          zoom: 8,

        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: buscarCoords(function(resultsObject){
                        new google.maps.LatLng(ConvertFromGrdToGoogle(resultsObject.result).LtLn);
                      }),
            map: map
        });

      }
```

In this code, ConvertFromGrdToGoogle is a function that,as it says, converts the datato a format that google will accept. it works and returns the coords like this:

```
[ '10.1850, -68.334',
  '10.1850, 68.334',
  '10.1853, -68.334',
  '10.1853, -68.334' ]
```

The problem right now is that, even though the map loads it doesn't show the markers.

Comment: A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two numbers as its arguments.  Not a string  with a comma in it (or an array of such strings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create the marker when you get data from your db, this code should works for you, you can see working on http://jsfiddle.net/victorv977/vX3Lc/ :

```
function initialize() {
//var location = new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.191);
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(10.191, -68.191),
    zoom: 8
 };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                              mapOptions);

buscarCoords(function(resultsObject) {
    var coordsArray = ConvertFromGrdToGoogle(resultsObject.result);
    for (var i = 0; i < coordsArray.length; i++) {
        var coords = coordsArray[i].split(", ");
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1])),
            map: map
        });
    };

});
}

function buscarCoords(callback) {
    var result = result;
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM monitoreo_actual', function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        callback({result:result});
    });
}
```

Comment: what you did there was great, actually i really thought it would work, but it still doesn't :S

Comment: the map loads and everything but it still won't display the markers

Comment: i'm sure the problem is that the markers are coming from inside the callback function "buscarCoords" so the initialize function won't read them. too bad i'm so rusty on scopes... and i don't know if i can call the variables inside the callback, from outside it

Comment: Hi I just make a fiddle for you with hardcoded values http://jsfiddle.net/victorv977/vX3Lc/ , hope its help.

Comment: thatks that will work great... just one more question..
i am using express for node.js, how can i load a script located in 'project/custom_modules/file.js' from an html view in 'project/views/index.html'?
I need to do that in order to call the function that will ultimately return the array

Comment: i've tried this way
<script type="text/javascript" src="../custom_modules/files.js"></script>
and many other relative paths, but it hasn't worked...
firebug says it cannot GET the file

Comment: Please mark the question as answererd, to server the file you need to confire your app:

mount server.configure(function(){
  server.use('/somefolder', express.static('./custom_modules/'));
  server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

<script type="text/javascript" src="somefolder/files.js"></script>

Comment: ok, getting closer, but now the variable returns to index.html as undefined. i'll try and find a way to get the actual content of the array.. thanks for everything

Comment: Create another question for your issue, I can help you.